# How to customize colors of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to configure the colors of this presentation?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\author[Subham Soni S. \& Mithun C.K. \& Karthikeyan \& Shantikumar L.]
{%
   \texorpdfstring{
        \begin{columns}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Subham Soni S.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Mithun C.K.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Karthikeyan\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
            \column{.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            Shantikumar L.\\
            \href{mailto:subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}{subhamsoni0049@pec.edu}
        \end{columns}
   }
   {John Doe \& Jane Doe}
}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For example, to green`and`dark green`.`

If yes, how to deal with this please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which colors exactly do you want to change? There are many colors involved in a `beamer` theme.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A color scheme (a color theme, is the right terminology) in `beamer` is controls many aspects. The simplest option would be to select a predefined `colortheme` with already provides colors like you want. The [`Beamer Theme Matrix`](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) gives you a quick overview of some of the already existing color themes (they correspond to columns in the matrix); the beamer `manual` also gives a description of the available themes.

A little example using `spruce`

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is not completely satisfactory, you can define your own color scheme using your desired colors. Now you will have to control the color for many elements, but changing the main ones (`structure` and the four palettes, and some other ones) you can quickly get a pretty good result. An example in which I chose as base the `PineGreen` color from the `dvipsnames` model

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=PineGreen!20,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black!80!black}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what kind of theme do you think is better to a project graduation's presentation? Because I need a theme that can show on its top lane the chapters and the current one? And please how to change the default english language?

Comment: @dgs Regarding the language, load `babel`, but pass the language as a class option, as in `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames},spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}` for `spanish`. Of course, this will work if your language is supported both for `babel` and `beamer`; in case it is not, please open a fresh new question. Regarding the theme, please refer to the `beamer` manual to learn the different options available; if none of them satisfies your requirements, please open a new question.

Comment: [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173867/any-theme-that-responds-to-these-requirements)