# Any theme that responds to these requirements?

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to make a presentation in which:

- The first page must include the subjet, authors, 2 coaches names and 2 logos at top, a footer which includes authors, subject, date and pages.
- The rest of pages, the only requirement is to have on top of the page all of the chapters and, the current chapter selected and its sections.

Is there any defined library for this kind of requirements? If not, how may to make this real please?

NOTE: that I'm currently having a long chapter name which has as length = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxxx".

Comment: A `beamer` presentation has no chapters. When you say "all of the chapters and, the current chapter selected and its sections" perhaps you meant "all of the sections and, the current chapter selected and its subsections"?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, you're right, that's it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possibility in which I used a modified version of the `split` outer theme; instead of `example-image-a` and `example-image-b` use the file names for your logos:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.35\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.35\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortdate\hfill
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=PineGreen!20,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=structure}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black!80!black}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\author[Author One \and Author Two]{
\texorpdfstring{
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Author One \\
    \href{mailto:authorone@tex.sx}{authorone@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}%       
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Author Two \\
    \href{mailto:authortwo@tex.sx}{authortwo@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}\\[2.5ex]      
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Advisor One \\
    \href{mailto:advisorone@tex.sx}{advisorone@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}%       
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Advisor Two \\
    \href{mailto:advisortwo@tex.sx}{advisortwo@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}%
   }{Author One and Author Two}
}
\title{Work Culture}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[PineGreen!75!black]
  (current page.north west)
  rectangle
  ([yshift=-1.7cm]current page.north east);
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west]
  at (current page.north west)
  {\includegraphics[height=1.7cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east]
  at (current page.north east)
  {\includegraphics[height=1.7cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two with a Really Really Really Long Title}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three Two}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three Three}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the title page:

[image]

An image of one of the frames in the second section, showing a long title. The left part contains the names for all section; the current section appears highlighted. The right part contains the name for all subsections of the current section; the current subsection appears highlighted.

[image]

### Update

In the comments it has been mentioned that the title of the presentation might be too long; in this case, there are two possibilities: either use the optional argument for `\title`, as in

```
\title[short title for footer]{long long long long title for the titlepage}
```

to provide a shorter version of the title that will go to the footer. If this is not an option and the long title must appear in the footer, then I'd propose a modification of the `footline` template like the one below. It also was requested to move down the logos in the titlepage:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \vbox{%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.33333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortdate\hfill
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.33333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,right]{author in head/foot}%
     \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=PineGreen!20,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=structure}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black!80!black}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white,fg=PineGreen}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\author[Author One \and Author Two]{
\texorpdfstring{
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Author One \\
    \href{mailto:authorone@tex.sx}{authorone@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}%       
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Author Two \\
    \href{mailto:authortwo@tex.sx}{authortwo@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}\\[2.5ex]      
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Advisor One \\
    \href{mailto:advisorone@tex.sx}{advisorone@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}%       
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    Advisor Two \\
    \href{mailto:advisortwo@tex.sx}{advisortwo@tex.sx}
  \end{minipage}%
   }{Author One and Author Two}
}
\title{A Really Really Really Really Really Really Long Title for the Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[PineGreen!75!black]
  (current page.north west)
  rectangle
  ([yshift=-0.75cm]current page.north east);
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west]
  at ([yshift=-0.75cm]current page.north west)
  {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east]
  at ([yshift=-0.75cm]current page.north east)
  {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two with a Really Really Really Long Title}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three One}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three Two}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test Subsection Three Three}
\begin{frame}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The new titlepage:

[image]

A zoomed image showing the new design for the new `footline`:

[image]

Comment: That's cool and thank you very much for your answer but I was talking about the subjet (title) of the presentation whom was too long to display in the footer not the section's title. I'm sorry if  I wasn't that clear.

Comment: @dgs can you use the optional argument for `\title` as in `\title[short title for the footer]{long long long long title for the title page}` or do you need the complete name to also appear in the footer? If the last option is the one you need (full title in footer), would you like to place the long title at the footer on one box of its own?

Comment: I can't find how did you put the footer date at left and the logos that I'm expecting to put in that page are very light, isn't it just possible to put them under that header line as 0.7 height size, please?

Comment: @dgs I updated my answer showing another possibility for the `footline` for long titles. Regarding your new requirement, what exactly do you mean with "0.7 height size"?

Comment: @dgs new update. I lowered the logos. Is something like that what you need? By the way, for future questions, please mention *all* the specifications from the beginning to avoid waste of time.

Comment: The dark green header, under which I'm trying to put these logos and before the subject.

Comment: Or may be, this way is better to see `\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}`, but how to insert the second logo on the left side ?

Comment: But using the line that I've written will mark a logo in each slide which isn't desired.

Comment: @dgs Please see this new update. Like that? You can move the logos vertically to the desired position by changing the value for `yshift` in my code.