# customization of TOC

Tags: beamer

How to set a TOC in which only appears sections without subsections?

**EDIT:** And on the beginning of a new section it shows only the content of it without displaying the header?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\author{Co.}
\title{Work Culture}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection
]
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Plan}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any good suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`?

Comment: By the way, your example doesn't contain a `\tableofcontents`, nor any `\section`s or `\subsection`s, which isn't helpful.

Comment: @Werner, I've updated my post. That've worked, but, what about the second question?

Comment: Are you referring to the general ToC or to the partial ToCs produced with `\AtBeginSubsection`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, to the partial ToCs.

Comment: Another question. What do you mean "it shows only the content of it without displaying the header?" Which header? What is "the content of it"?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, the header of each page contains sections and subsections, [like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173877/46158). So, the partial Toc needs to display the current section and its subsections.

Comment: @dgs: Please put some thought into your question rather than making the community guess what you're after. A clear, thought-out [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights your current problems would really be beneficial to the community.

Comment: @Werner, sorry but I'm trying my best. I'm beginner on this, I can not see clearly notions.

Comment: @dgs: That's when images come in handy. Compile some of your code, take a screen grab and draw it full of arrows and pointers to highlight what is going on and what *should* be going on instead.

Comment: Now I am confused. in your question you said "How to set a TOC in which only appears sections without subsections?" and in a comment "the partial Toc needs to display the current section and its subsections." Do you want subsections in the partial ToCs or not?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, The first question is for the general ToC which appears on after of the title page. And the second one is for the partial ToC which appears before each new reached section.

Comment: @dgs I provided an answer below. Is it something like that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, then the following settings will do what you want.

Using

```
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
```

the general ToC shows only the section entries. The settings

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
  \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-1.75ex}{}
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
```

will make the partial ToCs (at the beginning of each section) show only the current section and its subsection; the headline is locally suppressed for the partial ToCs and the frametitle is shifted vertically so it starts at the top of the frame.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\author{Co.}
\title{Work Culture}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
  \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-1.75ex}{}
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{General Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one one}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one three}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two one}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two three}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection three one}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection three two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection three three}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the general ToC:

[image]

An image of one of the partial ToCs (the one at the beginning of the second section):

[image]

Comment: I don't know why pdflatex is taking too long to compile. Just a second I'll check the render.

Comment: I'm not getting the subsections !

Comment: In fact, I'm using [your first posted code.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173877/46158)

Comment: @dgs My answer is independent of the theme used, so that's not a problem here. Where are you not getting the subsections in the general ToC or in the partial ones? Don't forget that you need to compile your document twice.

Comment: In the partial ones. I've compiled it twice.

Comment: @dgs As my example shows, subsections will show. If this is not the case for you, please edit your question and add there a simple example document (like the one in my answer) showing the problem. Also please attach an image of one of the partial ToCs that you are getting.

Comment: Oh it was because of this line `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`. Then how do I to set display only sections on the general ToC if I remove this to get the wondered render?

Comment: @dgs Please see my code. All you need for the general ToC is `\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]`.

Comment: @dgs You're welcome. I updated my answer adding        `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-1.75ex}{}` so the title in the partial ToC starts at the top. Change `-1.75ex` according to your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I've another question, in the same context : Is it possible to set some spaces between the section names in the partial toc?

Comment: @dgs feel free to ask a fresh new question.

Comment: Would you please help me [on this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175149/how-to-remove-the-header-of-the-tocs-page-and-to-place-the-tocs-title-at-top)?

Comment: @dgs Yes, of course. I've provided an answer.