# How to remove the header of the ToC's page and to place the ToC's title at top

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to remove the header of the ToC's page and to place its title at the top?
If it is, how, please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking but do you perhaps want `\begin{frame}[plain]` to remove the header etc. in the ToC frame?

Comment: @cfr, but that would remove the footer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can locally set the `headline` template to be empty and use `\addtobeamertemplate` to add an appropriate vertical skip before the frame title (depending on the used theme you might need to adjust the `1.7ex` I used in my example):

```
\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-1.7ex}{}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\endgroup
```

A complete example_

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-1.7ex}{}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please help me [on this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175496/how-to-display-videos) ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @dgs Unfortunately, I have no experience using `multimedia` or similar packages for video playing, so I'm afraid I cannot be of help on that one.