# How to display videos

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to include a video into my presentation using this code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
\movie[showcontrols,width=\linewidth]{}{c.avi}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But this wouldn't display the video, how do I to deal with this please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using? Based on [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158776/32374) it may be a problem with the viewer, not necessarily the PDF or LaTeX code...

Comment: @darthbith, Adobe Reader XI.

Comment: The `beamer` documentation states that `hyperref` must also be loaded with `multimedia`, but as the last package. Alternatively, you can use the [`media9`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) package instead of `multimedia`.