# How to make white-black themes Beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes, changes

I have problem that I want to change beamer themes to  be white -black themes beamer like this:

[image: black and white beamer]

From my code (**beamercolorthemefeminim.sty**):

```
\mode<presentation>
\definecolor{noir}{RGB}{255,255,255} % deep pink
\definecolor{blanc}{RGB}{0,0,,0} % white % merupakan bagian dari teks dibeamer
\definecolor{rouge}{RGB}{0,0,0} % chocolate
\definecolor{vert}{RGB}{0,0,0} % orange red
\definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{254,0,0} % gold


\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=noir} % latar belakang warna biru 
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blanc} % foreground warna putih 
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=noir} % foreground warna hijau 
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=vert} % foreground warna hijau

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blanc,bg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=rouge,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=bleu,bg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=rouge,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=bleu}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=blanc,bg=bleu}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=blanc,fg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=blanc,fg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=blanc,fg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{use=item,bg=blanc,fg=item.fg}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{use=block body, bg=block body.bg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=titlelike, bg=titlelike.bg, fg=titlelike.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{use=titlelike, fg=titlelike.fg, bg=titlelike.bg}

\setbeamercolor{logo}{use=block title, bg=block title.bg}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{fg=blanc,bg=blanc}

\mode<all>
```

And My MWE :

```
% Dokumen telah diedit oleh Hirwanto(hirwanto.iwan@yahoo.com) sesuai dengan keperluan yang ada tertanggal
% 25/09/2014, 10:31 AM
% Dapat digunakan secara gratis, bebas atau \emph{free}.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{feminim} % Perintah ini merupakan pilihan yang digunakan seperti cormorant(hitam/hijau)
                          % magpie(hitam/biru), dan frigatebird(merah/hitam)

\useoutertheme{infolines} % Perintah ini mengatur pada tampilan luar ;
                          % Pilihan outertheme : infolines, sidebar, dan tree

%\usepackage{polyglossia} % Perintah ini digunakan untuk pengaturan bahasa seperti bahasa jerman,dll yang
                          % termasuk dalam polyglossia , untuk melakukan kompilasi dokumen maka
                          % gunakan XeLaTeX

\title{R-S-I}                          % Judul
\subtitle{Riemann -Stieltjes Integral} % SubJudul
%--- Ini merupakan dokumen berjenis beamer khusus beamer darkthemes yang diciptakan oleh Damien Thiriet  dan didistribusikan pada 3 September 2014
\author[Hirwanto]{Hirwanto} % Bagian ini menjelaskan nama penulis
\institute[Universitas Gadjah Mada]{Program Studi Matematika\\ Fakultas Matematika dan Ilmu Pengetahuan Alama\\ Jurusan Matematika\\ Universitas Gadjah Mada} % Bagian ini menjelaskan institusi/univ. tempat kita kuliah
\date[2014]{Inisiasi Matematika, I} % Bagian ini menjelaskan tgl, bln, atau pembuatannya,
                                    % Boleh juga judul seminar yang diikuti,
%\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.3cm]{logougm.png}} % Bagian ini memuat logo univ, inst, atau company

\begin{document} % Perintah membuat dokumen dalam LaTeX

\begin{frame} % Perintah membuat frame baru
  \titlepage  % Perintah membuat judul halaman
  %\tableofcontents % Perintah ini menampilkan daftar isi dibagian depan
\end{frame}   % Akhir dari frame
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents % Perintah ini menampilkan daftar isi namun dengan halaman baru/frame baru
\end{frame}
\section{Pendahuluan} % Sub bagian
\subsection{Spesifikasi} % Sub sub

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Pembahasan} % Judul pada frame

  \begin{block}{Teorema Begin (\emph{Kesamaan Segitiga})} % Membuat blok pada frame
     Lorem Ipsum ...
  \end{block}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Proposisi} % Membuat frame untuk contoh biasanya frame ini berbeda dengan yang lainnya
    \begin{description} % Perintah deskripsi sama seperti list, enumerate, atau case
       \item[Tail] Tail is sometimes like a Lion Angle
       \item[Curve] Curve is language program abstract
       \item[Rope] Rope is not like a tail
    \end{description}
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Environnement}


%\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{Pembahasan} % Judul Frame
%\framesubtitle{Gross Holic, \emph{Payment}, Hurricane, 1887} % Sub judul pada frame
%\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{dahut.jpg} % Perintah menyisipkan gambar ex : .jpg, .png

%Cool, prey.
%\end{frame}

\section{Kesimpulan}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Begin}

   \begin{itemize} % Perintah item list,
      \item \structure{Eternal} Frame  \alert{An Alien of Aliention}
      \item Some Practice can make you better .
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document} % Akhir dokumen LaTeX selamat mengerjakan
```

Comment: How about providing the community with a *complete*, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than just some preamble stuff. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Also give some clear instruction on which elements should be black and white, since you've defined some colours that are not all black or white...

Comment: @Werner I just a copy from darkbeamer themes , you can check file at darkbeamerthemes

Comment: That won't provide an MWE, though, as it is a theme. It is not meant to be compiled. In any case, as Werner says, the question isn't currently clear given the inclusion of colours which are neither black nor white.

Comment: @cfr I don't know how to make a black -white beamerthemes

Comment: @cfr I make my screenshoot from Microsoft Word and I want to  make a black - white themes at Beamer LaTeX,

Answer (score 2):

Here my Answer, from [Gonzalo Medina Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173853/how-to-customize-colors-of-a-beamer-presentation)

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=white,fg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black!80!black}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=black,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body exampel}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\title{R-S-I}                          % Judul
\subtitle{Riemann -Stieltjes Integral} % SubJudul
%--- Ini merupakan dokumen berjenis beamer khusus beamer darkthemes yang diciptakan oleh Damien Thiriet  dan didistribusikan pada 3 September 2014
\author[Hirwanto]{Hirwanto} % Bagian ini menjelaskan nama penulis
\institute[UGM]{Program Studi Matematika\\ Fakultas Matematika dan Ilmu Pengetahuan Alam\\ Jurusan Matematika\\ Universitas Gadjah Mada} % Bagian ini menjelaskan institusi/univ. tempat kita kuliah
\date[2014]{Inisiasi Matematika, I} % Bagian ini menjelaskan tgl, bln, atau pembuatannya,
                                    % Boleh juga judul seminar yang diikuti,
%\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.3cm]{logougm.png}} % Bagian ini memuat logo univ, inst, atau company

\begin{document} % Perintah membuat dokumen dalam LaTeX

\begin{frame} % Perintah membuat frame baru
  \titlepage  % Perintah membuat judul halaman
  %\tableofcontents % Perintah ini menampilkan daftar isi dibagian depan
\end{frame}   % Akhir dari frame
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents % Perintah ini menampilkan daftar isi namun dengan halaman baru/frame baru
\end{frame}
\section{Pendahuluan} % Sub bagian
\subsection{Spesifikasi} % Sub sub

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Pembahasan} % Judul pada frame

  \begin{block}{Teorema Begin (\emph{Kesamaan Segitiga})} % Membuat blok pada frame
     Lorem Ipsum ...
  \end{block}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Proposisi} % Membuat frame untuk contoh biasanya frame ini berbeda dengan yang lainnya
    \begin{description} % Perintah deskripsi sama seperti list, enumerate, atau case
       \item[Tail] Tail is sometimes like a Lion Angle
       \item[Curve] Curve is language program abstract
       \item[Rope] Rope is not like a tail
    \end{description}
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Environnement}


%\begin{frame}
   %\frametitle{Pembahasan} % Judul Frame
   %\framesubtitle{Gross Holic, \emph{Payment}, Hurricane, 1887} % Sub judul pada frame
  % \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{dahut.jpg} % Perintah menyisipkan gambar ex : .jpg, .png

 %  Cool, prey.
%\end{frame}

\section{Kesimpulan}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Begin}

   \begin{itemize} % Perintah item list,
      \item \structure{Eternal} Frame  \alert{An Alien of Aliention}
      \item Some Practice can make you better .
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Intisari}
\begin{tabular}{p{11.5cm}}
Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada Pada skripsi ini akan dibahas mengenai persamaan diferensial , pada\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document} % Akhir dokumen LaTeX selamat mengerjakan
```

And , I will get the result like this :
[image: Black and White themebeamer]

**It's not pure black -white  theme beamer**

Comment: ´\setbeamercolor{example text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black!80!black}´

Comment: block body **exampel**